# Whats to change? Java

Tags: java, minecraft

```
[SEVERE] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.minecraft.server.ContainerEnchantTable.doEnchantment(Lnet/minecraft/server/EntityHuman;Ljava/util/List;IZ)Z
2012-04-09 13:34:42 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.mod_MultiplayerSupport.doEnchant(mod_MultiplayerSupport.java:80)
2012-04-09 13:34:42 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.mod_MultiplayerSupport.handlePacket(mod_MultiplayerSupport.java:51)
2012-04-09 13:34:42 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.ModLoaderMp.handleAllPackets(ModLoaderMp.java:110)
2012-04-09 13:34:42 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.Packet230ModLoader.handle(Packet230ModLoader.java:158)
2012-04-09 13:34:42 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.NetworkManager.b(NetworkManager.java:234)
2012-04-09 13:34:42 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.a(NetServerHandler.java:118)
2012-04-09 13:34:42 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.NetworkListenThread.a(NetworkListenThread.java:78)
2012-04-09 13:34:42 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:557)
2012-04-09 13:34:42 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:455)
2012-04-09 13:34:42 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:490)
2012-04-09 13:34:42 [SEVERE] Unexpected exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.minecraft.server.ContainerEnchantTable.doEnchantment(Lnet/minecraft/server/EntityHuman;Ljava/util/List;IZ)Z
    at net.minecraft.server.mod_MultiplayerSupport.doEnchant(mod_MultiplayerSupport.java:80)
    at net.minecraft.server.mod_MultiplayerSupport.handlePacket(mod_MultiplayerSupport.java:51)
    at net.minecraft.server.ModLoaderMp.handleAllPackets(ModLoaderMp.java:110)
    at net.minecraft.server.Packet230ModLoader.handle(Packet230ModLoader.java:158)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetworkManager.b(NetworkManager.java:234)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.a(NetServerHandler.java:118)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetworkListenThread.a(NetworkListenThread.java:78)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:557)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:455)
    at net.minecraft.server.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:490)
```

Comment: I don't see any question, neither any description of what you've tried so far. Voting to close the question as not a real question.

Answer (score 2):

"No such method" suggests to me that the JAR containing that class is out of date.  Some object in the code is calling a method with a signature that differs from what's in the JAR. Find the JAR where that class lives and Google for an update.